# Tumblr API V2 Error code 429: "Rate Limit Exceeded" You are being rate limited, slow down. Header info?

Tags: php, api, tumblr, php-5.3

I tested Tumblr API with PHP, then I try to follow with friends using API and worked successfully, then later I get this error:

Error 429 "Rate Limit Exceeded"

I heard I need to wait 1 hour and limits will gone.
Also I see a few information about headers:

```
x_ratelimit_api_followers_limit
x_ratelimit_api_followers_remaining
x_ratelimit_api_followers_reset
```

This informations can be in header. What header? Oauth? I don't found that.
How can I see this variables?
How can I get more information about API follower limitations?
Tumblr's API documentation not contain that.

Comment: Did you look at the contents of the response? As in, the actual body itself?

Comment: I see the contents of response and it not contains any information about this x_ratelimit infos... It's like 2 object, as documented for example: 1. meta: status=200, etc... 2. response: with post_id, etc... I checked the oauth answer header but still nothing about this limits. Maybe I need to check as different way.

Comment: You can only fetch X many followers per minute with the API. This is represented in the `x_ratelimit_api_...` headers.  These fields in the header inform you what the limit is, how many more calls to the API you can make, and when the limit will expire so that you can start using that API endpoint again.  This is not in the documentation, but please see the [Tumblr API Discussion Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tumblr-api) where there are posts dealing with this issue.

Comment: Felix Bonkoski: I duped the header but I see no *ratelimit* named info at header. I used PHP 5.3 + Oauth. How can I see this header infos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer provided [by Felix Bonkoski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1456377/felix-bonkoski):

> *You can only fetch X many followers per minute with the API. This is represented in the x_ratelimit_api_... headers. These fields in the header inform you what the limit is, how many more calls to the API you can make, and when the limit will expire so that you can start using that API endpoint again. This is not in the documentation, but please see the [Tumblr API Discussion Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tumblr-api) where there are posts dealing with this issue.*